# AngularJS forms validation onchange not called until minlength met

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I ran into this working on a form and was wondering if it was a bug or a work around.

I have a password field with a ng-minlength directive set and a ng-change directive set with a function that does additional validation.  The ng-change doesn't appear to be called until the minlength is met.

Is this by design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is by design. This question has a workaround answer to your problem:

[Angular.js - ng-change not firing when ng-pattern is $invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20865507/angular-js-ng-change-not-firing-when-ng-pattern-is-invalid)

Comment: The OP is not using ng-pattern.

Comment: It looks to be a similar issue, my workaround was to just include a new "minimum" custom validator in my ng-change function. it just seems silly that I have to do that when ng-minlength already exists.

Comment: @JoelSkrepnek No way. Really? Did you even look at the solution in the link?

Comment: @Snowburnt `ng-change` serves the purpose it does, and for that reason creating a new change directive is the more appropriate approach, as `ng-minlength` already works correctly.

Comment: I did.  And I read the linked issue.  Neither apply to this situation.  This is not by design, although there appears to be an unrelated issue.  See answer.

Comment: I retract that.  What threw me off was that change *was* firing when the input was empty.  Sorry!