# AngularJS watch not working

Tags: angularjs, watch

A watch is not working.
I ng-include the following content:

```
<form class="search">
    <div class="searchbar">
        <input type="search" value="" data-ng-model="searchKeyword" placeholder="zoeken">
        <button type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
    </div>
</form>
```

like this:

```
<div ng-include src="filterPath" onload="initiateSearch()"></div>
```

The onload function is doing this:

```
(function(){
    var appController = angular.module('ListerAppController', []);

    appController.controller('ListerCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$http', '$filter', '$timeout', '$sharedFactories', 'History', '$location',
        function($scope, $rootScope, $http, $filter, $timeout, $sharedFactories, History, $location) {
            $scope.initiateSearch = function () {
            // This is what you will bind the filter to
                $scope.filterText = '';

                // Instantiate these variables outside the watch
                var tempFilterText = '',
                    filterTextTimeout;

                $scope.$watch('searchKeyword', function (val) {
                    if (filterTextTimeout) $timeout.cancel(filterTextTimeout);

                    tempFilterText = val;

                    filterTextTimeout = $timeout(function() {
                        $scope.filterText = tempFilterText;
                        $scope.pageCount = function() {
                            return Math.ceil( $scope.itemsfiltered.length / $scope.itemsPerPage );
                    };
                }, 350); // delay 250 ms
            });
        };
    }]);
})();
```

Everything seems to go allright but... the $watch on searchKeyword never fires the function when I start typing in the input element called searchKeyword.

Comment: put `watch` inside the controller not inside the `initiateSearch`

Comment: what is `onload` supposed to do on a `<div>`? Especially since it is trying to call a method that is in angular scope. Call your method in the controller

Comment: Why do you inject $rootScope? Are you using it somewhere but you have removed that part from your code sample? I usually try to avoid using $rootScope unless no other choice, but there's always a better solution usually. This IMO isn't the source of your problem, just curious.

Comment: The onload is calling a method inside the controller when the ng-include for the template is done loading. When it's ready the element with ng-model="searchKeyword" excists. And then I want to apply the $scope.$watch('searchKeyword', function(){}). The problem is that it's inside a $scope.initiateSearch = function () {}. Putting the watch outside the scope function makes it work again

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The watch has to be an attribute of the object, not the object itself, see the example here  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope on how to add a watch, and the use of the model here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input. 
You could try this (I have not tested it)

```
data-ng-model="search.keyword"
```

and in your controller:

```
$scope.search = {}
```

...

```
$scope.$watch('search.keyword', ...
```

Comment: what if I use the model in a ng-repat ? For instance, for the following, the $watch doesnt' works :

`<md-checkbox ng-repeat="project in tree" aria-label="{{tree.name}}" ng-model="filter.projects[project.id]" ng-init="true">{{project.name}}</md-checkbox>`

Answer (score 45):

Have you tried adding `true`, as bellow?

```
$scope.$watch('searchKeyword', function (val) {
 /* your logic here */                    
}, true);
```

If you're curious about what the `true` is, here's the function signature from [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope):

```
$watch(watchExpression, listener, [objectEquality]);
```

> When objectEquality == true, inequality of the watchExpression is determined according to the angular.equals function. To save the value of the object for later comparison, the angular.copy function is used. This therefore means that watching complex objects will have adverse memory and performance implications.

So apparently the significant thing is that it checks the equality of the old value and new value in a different way. I could see this being necessary if (correct me if I'm wrong) the value you're watching is, e.g., an array as opposed to a string.

Comment: Ahh.. this worked for me. Was trying to catch changes in an object, but wasn't watching deep enough. Cheers.

Comment: any nesting of objects will need this. nice answer.

Comment: If you only need a shallow watch of an object or an array instead of a deep watch, use `$watchCollection` instead https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to the list of possible solutions:

While using forms:

Using ng-pattern will supress the call to $watch unless and until the input is validated by ng-pattern.

So just in case, if anyone is using ng-pattern, try $watch after removing ng-pattern.

For more reading:

[Angular.js - ng-change not firing when ng-pattern is $invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20865507/angular-js-ng-change-not-firing-when-ng-pattern-is-invalid)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest one is to pass true as the last argument of $watch.

For more reading:

https://github.com/mbenford/ngTagsInput/issues/174