# Angular-XEditable e-onChange

Tags: angularjs, x-editable

Here is my code

```
<span editable-select="item.text" e-ng-options="p.id as p.name for p in products" e-form="rowform" 
          onbeforesave="checkName($data)" e-required e-name="name" 
          e-onChange="scopeFunction($data)">
      {{ showProductName(item.text) || 'Enter Name of a product' }}
    </span>
```

Is it possible to access controller's $scope in e-onChange?

If I enter e-onChange="scopeFunction(data)" it throws an error "ReferenceError: scopeFunction not defined"

What I want is after selecting a new value to be able to change another field's value.

Comment: I wanted to also add that I want the change event to fire before I save the value.

Comment: cannot use onaftersave instead of e-onChange?

Comment: can you show your controller's code?

Comment: Hey, I think I managed to do it via onaftersave. I decided to just leave it. Onaftersave doesn't exactly do what I wanted because I wanted another cell's value to change when a user enters some value in the selected editable cell input (before I click "save" changes).

Comment: yes, I have the same problem.  i need to change a 2nd cell based on a first cell's change.  Xeditable doesn't seem to let you do that during edit mode.

Answer (score 12):

Use angular's `e-ng-change` instead (with the 'e-'-prefix for the editable element):

```
<span editable-select="item.text" 
    e-ng-options="p.id as p.name for p in products" e-form="rowform" 
    onbeforesave="checkName($data)" e-required e-name="name" 
    e-ng-change="scopeFunction($data)">
        {{ showProductName(item.text) || 'Enter Name of a product' }}
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use e-ng-change="onChange(field)" with e-ng-model-options="{allowInvalid:true}" to trigger onChange events

```
                   <input 
                      type="text" ng-model="newEntity[field.name]"
                      name="{{field.name}}" placeholder="{{field.placeholder}}"
                      value="{{field.defaultValue}}"
                      e-ng-change="onChange(field)"
                      e-ng-model-options="{allowInvalid:true}"
                   />
```

Note: e-ng-model-options will help tracking onChange events even if ng-pattern is $invalid.
See More: [Angular.js - ng-change not firing when ng-pattern is $invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20865507/angular-js-ng-change-not-firing-when-ng-pattern-is-invalid)